# Creating a leaderboard using Facebook APIs and the PHP SDK

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm a new Facebook developer. I'm creating a game and want to include a leader board.

I'd like to build a fairly detailed leader board including the following information:

1) Name
2) Pic_Square or profile_pic
3) A general location (UK, USA or LONDON, NY)
4) Score

I'm aware of how to get a current users basic information from the either the old REST API or the Graph API. However from what I understand of the Facebook rules I can't store the information I want to use from the API.

This leads me to the conclusion I should be polling the Facebook API using the information I can store (FB user ID's). When querying the API for specific user ID's (the ones for the test users I have generated) API methods (user.getInfo and fql.query) return either just the ID of the user or the fields I have requested with null values.

When querying my own ID I can access all the data.

Are there any methods to obtain publicly available data via the any of the  APIs?

Thanks for your help!

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think that you can't store this info? On the [user table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) page it even says:

> You can cache this data and subscribe to real time updates on any of its fields which are also fields in the corresponding Graph API version.

If you request `offline_access` permission you would be able to get user information even when a user is not currently logged in to your app.

You should be able to get any user public info without permissions or access token by going to:

`https://graph.facebook.com/<USER_ID>`

To display avatar you can use this code:

`<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<USER_ID>/picture"/>`

I don't think you would be able to get location without requesting extra permissions.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight! 
I think I got the wrong end of the stick from the documentation on the 'users.getStandardInfo' method. 

Ben

Comment: Would you also happen to know how I could get the applications installed by the user data?

Comment: @Shouvik No, sorry. Just create a separated question.

Comment: ah thanks never mind.. I think I have to spend some **quality time** with the graph API :)